# Can all such Astromech droids stand up like this?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, droids, r2-d2, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian* we see an Astromech droid extremely similar to R2-D2 (but a different unit) stand up like a person with 2 arms and 2 legs. Can all such units do this? Specifically, I'm wondering if R2-D2 could. Canon answers are preferred but Legends is okay too.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen an R2 unit stand up like that, and we have a pretty good idea what they look like on the inside. [image] I think it must be a custom modification.

Answer (score 1):

Just pitching in my two cents.  It looks like someone found a Astromech droid and attached robotic arms and legs.  The droid looks very crude and it looks like there were just a lot of modifications.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an astromech, or an R2 unit.

It's a droid of a different construction, that happens to have a similar upper shell and head area (in terms of shape and colouring), that rows a boat.

Darth Bombad has already shown that R2 units do not have such appendages.

There is no reason to think, after all this time, that R2-D2 could stand up like this just because a droid with a similar head could do so.

(Out of universe, I expect the similarity was intentional, to make us think the droid *were* an R2 unit for as long as its limbs were obscured by the rock.)

Comment: It may be a *modified* R2 unit.

Comment: It may be, but then it's still not a R2 unit. Or an astromech :)